# JQuery Equivalence to Prototype Code

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

What would be the jQuery equivalent to this Prototype code?

If you don't think this is relevant and close it, would you mind messaging me directly with a solution?

```
var comment_link = new Element('a', {
    'title': "View snapshot", 
    'id': snapshot.id + '_comment', 
    'href': "#", 
    'class': ""
}).update(snapshot.name.truncate(13));

comment_link.observe('click', respondToClick);
comment_link.observe('mouseover', respondToMouseOver);
comment_link.observe('mouseout', respondToMouseOut);
```

I tried this to no avail:

```
var comment_link = new $j('<a/>', {
    title: "View snapshot", 
    id: snapshot.id + '_comment', 
    href: "#", 
    class: ""
}).html(snapshot.name.truncate(13));

$j(comment_link).click(respondToClick);
$j(comment_link).mouseover(respondToMouseOver);
$j(comment_link).mouseout(respondToMouseOut);
```

Comment: There's no DM on SO ;) Also, you might wanna show us some more context ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var comment_link = $j('<a/>')
  .attr('title', 'View snapshot')
  .attr('id', snapshot.id + '_comment')
  .attr('href', '#')
  .html(snapshot.name.truncate(13))
  .click(respondToClick)
  .mouseover(respondToMouseOver)
  .mouseout(respondToMouseOut);
```

should do it